# Print in Windows 10 does not generate file or job

Tags: c++, windows, printers, temp

In windows 10 and windows 7 set up , we have user account who is not part of Administrators group.

When we invoke print from our application which is running under user account, we could get files printed in configured printer in windows 7.

In windows 10, when we send files to printer, there are no print jobs sent for printer. When we print as PDF using Microsoft Print to PDF, either files are not generated in output folder or created with 0 bytes.

On investigation, we observed that when user account is provided full permission to C:\TEMP directory, print is working in windows 10.

However, in windows 7 also user account did not have full permission.

Also, we observed that not only our application but windows regedit.exe also does not print when run under user account. But NotePad.exe prints in user account.

Comment: We need a [mcve] but at a guess the `TEMP` environment variable has been overridden for that user, Windows doesn't use `c:\temp` as a temporary directory by default

Comment: sample code is not required for this use case. Performing File->Print from Regedit.exe or excel from user account would reproduce issue in windows 10

Comment: Printing from regedit in windows 10 works for me. A [mcve] doesn't necessarily need to include sample code but it does need to provide enough information for someone else to reproduce the problem